# Qt - counting selected QTableItemWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I want to count QTableItemWidget which I've already selected,

Here is my code:

```
connect(m_table, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTableWidgetItem *)), this, SLOT(onItemClicked(QTableWidgetItem *)));
int onItemClicked(QTableWidgetItem *item)
{
  QString imageName;
  imageName = item->data(Qt::UserRole).toString();
  if (!m_editMode){
    openMedia(imageName);
    QTimer::singleShot(50, m_table->selectionModel(), SLOT(clear()));
  }    
  else{
    m_editBar->setTitle(QString::number(m_table->selectionModel()->selectedRows().count()));
  }
}
```

But `m_table->selectionModel()->selectedRows().count()` is always 0 . any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to process selection, connect to the `selectionChanged` signal of the selection model of  `QTableWidget`. It is cleaner and is guaranteed to work. Also, signals returning a value are not useful in Qt unless you call them as normal functions directly

Answer (score 1):

Selected rows is only active when all elements of a row are selected; it returns a list of all the selected rows (see [isRowSelected](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#isRowSelected)).
Columns works the same.

Here, selected rows count is 1, row 2 is selected:

[image: QTableView]

If you want to count the number of selected items in the widget (4 in the image case), you should use:

```
m_table->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
selectItems = m_table->selectedItems().count();
m_table->setSelectionMode(QTableView::MultiSelection);
```

MultiSelection lets you select multi selection.